# Sum between a range in a sparsely populated array in less than O(n)?

Tags: algorithm

Suppose there is a array with huge size and only few positions filled up. I need to find the sum between some position a and position b, a < b.

Can I do better than O(n)? If yes, how?

Comment: You cannot do better then O(n). As the size b - a will always be of the form (n / x) where x is a positive number. And you will have to go through the whole length of b - a.

Comment: If i recieve data in a stream, can I construct a tree or some other structure to improve summation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use Binary Indexed Tree (or a segment tree) to do `O(logN)` queries.

https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/binary-indexed-trees/
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree

Comment: Once again, data structures to the rescue. Thanks for the link

Comment: Well of course if you take the construction time into account then it's by definition impossible to do it faster than `O(N)`. OP was unclear with whether they cared about construction complexity or not.

Answer (score 0):

If your sparse array is implemented as a naive, native array (e.g. `int[999999]`) then there is no faster way than manual iteration in `O(n/p)` time (where `p` is the number of hardware threads you have).

If your sparse array is stored in a storage-optimal format (e.g. an array of pages or linked-list-of-pages), then the fastest is `O(m/p)` where `m` is the number of pages and `p` is the number of hardware threads.

UPDATE:

In your comment you remarked you wanted a single-threaded solution that runs faster than `O(n)`. This is impossible. Consider this sparse-array:

```
arr = [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ]
```

A computer cannot "see" an array all-at-once like a human eye+brain does. A single-threaded computer can only process data one word (typically 32 or 64-bits) at a time. All the computer knows is that there's an array inside `arr`, so it starts reading it, it sees `0`, then it reads again `0`, and so on, reading 11 `0`s until it finally encounters the `1` value. This is the `O(n)` solution.

The only way to beat this is using parallelisation: a human-eye+brain could be considered as a machine with over 576 million threads (90-degrees of the human-eye [has 576 megapixels](http://www.clarkvision.com/articles/eye-resolution.html)) which "sees" the entire array in my StackOverflow posting instantly (`O(1)`). For a computer to do the same your program would have to have many threads (with a pre-programmed data-offset) which simultaneously reads the array which then gives you the answer:

```
void Main() {
    // Setup the threads
    volatile int total = 0;
    WaitHandle ev = new WaitHandle();
    Int32[] arr;
    ev.Reset();
    for(int i=0; i < 100; i++) {
        (new Thread( delegate() {
            int offset = i;
            ev.WaitOne();
            total += arr[offset]; // assume this is a magic thread-safe increment operation

        } )).Start();
    }

    // Load the array
    Int32[] arr = new Int32[] { /* 100 values */ };
    ev.Set(); // unblock all 100 threads instantly

    // assume there's a magic Thread.Join() wait here

    Console.WriteLine("Total: {0}.", total);
}
```

That is the only way to get `O(1)` time to compute the sum of a sparse array, in a mathematically sound way.

...however even that is impossible, because no "magic thread-safe addition" operation exists. The best you can do is `m`-levels of intermediate addition operations (where `m` is some `Log[X](n)` value), but it's still very close to `O(1)`.

Comment: But `n` is the size of the range `b-a` and not the size of the list, right?

Comment: Thats an interesting approach. But I would really appreciate a single threaded solution, with either a  lower bound or better complexity.

Comment: @Jasper `n == b-a` in this case. `n` is an abstraction of "the number of items through which to search". Though if you're using a storage-optimal approach then you cannot seek to arbitrary indexes in `O(1)` time unless you're using a hashtable to track page addresses.